# In Minecraft, I put the Nether portal exactly how it should be but it won't light why?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I've been trying to light my nether portal but it doesn't work. I have the portal set up correctly but it still won't work. The portal doesn't show up. Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: Because there **is** no Nether in the Pocket Edition. You need to use a Nether Reactor.

Comment: How do I use that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Minecraft Pocket Edition you can't go to the nether. Instead you have the Nether Reactor, follow the instructions below to make it.

C = Cobblestone
G = Gold Block
N = Nether Reactor Core
A = Air
. = Spacing to make my diagram look right

**Bottom Layer**

G  C  G
C  C  C
G  C  G

**Middle Layer**

C  A  C
A  N  A
C  A  C

**Top Layer (3 blocks off the ground)**

A  C  A
C  C  C
A  C  A

**Done!**

Now you just tap it to activate it and it will spawn a giant room out of netherack. Inside will spawn Zombie Pigmen to attack you while random items spawn inside the room. After 45 seconds the nether reactor will burn out and you will lose the gold blocks, meanwhile holes will appear in the walls to let you out and the Pigmen and items will stop spawning. When you leave you'll find it changed the time to night. To make a Nether Reactor Core follow the instructions below.

I = Iron
D = Diamond

**Crafting Recipe**

I  D  I
I  D  I
I  D  I

Comment: Last time I did that Zombie Pigman didn't show up

Comment: Probably on peaceful. That happened to me when I did it.